# How to remove <meta-data> from chatsdk core android?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have used chatsdk library in my android application. I have to remove following meta-data from chatsdk manifest.

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
            android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />
```

I removed this meta-data but when i again run my application, it is generated again, not removing.
My application has also a manifest file. How can i remove this from chatsdk library manifest file?

Comment: To modify code of library you need to add it as module . Do you already have it as module ?

Comment: i only added as dependency in build.gradle